# GCP MySQL Automatic database replication for staging

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Currently we have an MySQL instance on GCP, this is used for production reasons. But now we want to implement a staging instance, and I want that this staging instance would be always updated with the production database.

I would like to know if I could schedule one a day a task in order to duplicate the production instance into de staging one.

Thank you!

Now there are automatic backups that GCP create by itself at the morning, but the thing is that I need those backups to restore into the staging database automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Now there are automatic backups that GCP create by itself at the
> morning, but the thing is that I need those backups to restore into
> the staging database automatically.

One solution is to schedule a job to run the restoration task:

```
gcloud sql backups restore BACKUP_ID \
--restore-instance=TARGET_INSTANCE_NAME \
--backup-instance=SOURCE_INSTANCE_NAME
```

Refer this documentation for other restoration methods - [Restore to a different instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring#restorebackups-another-instance)

Before restoring check the [Tips and requirements for restoring to a different instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restore#tips-restore-different-instance)